# cf env <application-name> doesn't return the expected json in watson developer cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

Result is expected to get

```html
System-Provided:
{
"VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "speech_to_text": [{
      "credentials": {
        "url": "<url>",
        "password": "<password>",
        "username": "<username>"
      },
    "label": "speech-to-text",
    "name": "speech-to-text-service-standard",
    "plan": "standard"
 }]
}
}
```

But the exact result I get

[Actual Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq5rL.png)

And the app is not properly working

Comment: what version of `cf` cli are you using? `cf -v` would tell you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the output of the actual results, there is no services bound to your application.

You have to run the following command to bind your servicer to your application:

`cf bind-service speech-to-text-converter speech-to-text-service-standard`